# "How to" use "how to"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, questions

How.

Is it grammatically correct to phrase a question starting with "How to"?

We see "How To" videos that explain how to do something, but is the question form valid English?

Example:

How to add two numbers?

vs

Do you know how to add two numbers?

Comment: This is Off Topic General Reference for ELU. It should be migrated to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Err, I'm an american and english is my first language...

Comment: ELL isn't just for non-native speakers. It's for *learning the basics* - which obviously includes such things as recognising that [***How to do X** is not a question but an **NP, a clause which behaves like a noun***](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/20734/126)